# setup a Maven Wrapper for my project with io.takari

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I want to setup the Maven Wrapper (The Maven Wrapper is an easy way to ensure a user of your Maven build has everything necessary to run your Maven build) for my project.
I will use the Takari Maven Plugin with its provided wrapper goal. 
I execute the following command:

```
mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper
```

But I got this error

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.takari:maven:0.4.1:wrapper (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Error installing the maven-wrapper archive. Cannot determine the type of archive C:\Users\carbonell\.m2\repository\io\takari\maven-wrapper\0.2.1\maven-wrapper-0.2.1.tar.gz. Input is not in the .gz for
mat -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.takari:maven:0.4.1:wrapper (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Error installing the maven-wrapper archive.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error installing the maven-wrapper archive.
        at io.takari.maven.plugins.WrapperMojo.execute(WrapperMojo.java:67)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot determine the type of archive C:\Users\carbonell\.m2\repository\io\takari\maven-wrapper\0.2.1\maven-wrapper-0.2.1.tar.gz.
        at io.tesla.proviso.archive.tar.TarGzArchiveSource.<init>(TarGzArchiveSource.java:29)
        at io.tesla.proviso.archive.tar.TarGzArchiveHandler.getArchiveSource(TarGzArchiveHandler.java:44)
        at io.tesla.proviso.archive.UnArchiver.unarchive(UnArchiver.java:54)
        at io.tesla.proviso.archive.UnArchiver.unarchive(UnArchiver.java:44)
        at io.takari.maven.plugins.WrapperMojo.execute(WrapperMojo.java:60)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input is not in the .gz format
        at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorInputStream.init(GzipCompressorInputStream.java:164)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorInputStream.<init>(GzipCompressorInputStream.java:137)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorInputStream.<init>(GzipCompressorInputStream.java:102)
        at io.tesla.proviso.archive.tar.TarGzArchiveHandler.getInputStream(TarGzArchiveHandler.java:34)
        at io.tesla.proviso.archive.tar.TarGzArchiveSource.<init>(TarGzArchiveSource.java:27)
        ... 26 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: `Connection refused:` apparently you are behind a firewall/proxy, leading to a HTML page being download a s the archive instead of the archive.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this for posterity.

I got this on my second attempt to run this goal.

The first attempt failed with "Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message" because Maven couldn't get through my company proxy.  I don't know why or how it was bypassing our internal repository configured in settings.xml.  This left me with an empty gzip file at the location specified in that error message.

The second attempt produced the same error you received because the gzip file was empty.

I had to cheat a little and configure Maven via MAVEN_OPTS to use the proxy in order to download all of the necessary artifacts.